# connect by prior delivers unexpected results

Tags: sql, oracle

This select statement delivers strange results:

```
with data(id, seqno, cs_prev_seqno, descr) as
 (select 1, 1, 0, 'Id 1 Step1' from dual
  union all
  select 1, 2, 1, 'Id 1 Step2' from dual
  union all
  select 1, 3, 2, 'Id 1 Step3' from dual
  union all
  select 1, 4, 1, 'Id 1 Step4' from dual      
  union all
  select 2, 1, 0, 'Id 2 Step1' from dual
  union all
  select 2, 2, 1, 'Id 2 Step2' from dual)

select id,
       sys_connect_by_path(seqno, '/') as path,
       seqno,
       cs_prev_seqno,
       descr,
       level
  from data
 where id = 1
connect by prior seqno = cs_prev_seqno
 start with cs_prev_seqno = 0;
```

I expected that the `connect by` is only done for rows with id=1, but the results are:

```
id path   seq seq_prev descr       level
1 /1      1   0        Id 1 Step1  1
1 /1/2    2   1        Id 1 Step2  2
1 /1/2/3  3   2        Id 1 Step3  3
1 /1/2/3  3   2        Id 1 Step3  3
1 /1/4    4   1        Id 1 Step4  2
1 /1/2    2   1        Id 1 Step2  2
1 /1/2/3  3   2        Id 1 Step3  3
1 /1/2/3  3   2        Id 1 Step3  3
1 /1/4    4   1        Id 1 Step4  2
```

I.E. first of all the `connect by` is done for all rows, afterwards the result is filtered by id.

As a workaround, the following statement delivers the correct results:

```
with data(id,
seqno,
cs_prev_seqno,
descr) as
 (select 1, 1, 0, 'Id 1 Step1'
    from dual
  union all
  select 1, 2, 1, 'Id 1 Step2'
    from dual
  union all
  select 1, 3, 2, 'Id 1 Step3'
    from dual
  union all
  select 1, 4, 1, 'Id 1 Step4'
    from dual

  union all
  select 2, 1, 0, 'Id 2 Step1'
    from dual
  union all
  select 2, 2, 1, 'Id 2 Step2'
    from dual

  )

,
data2 as
 (select d.id,
         d.seqno,
         d.cs_prev_seqno,
         d.id || '.' || d.seqno as id_seqno,
         d.id || '.' || d.cs_prev_seqno as cs_id_prev_seqno,
         d.descr
    from data d)

select id,
       sys_connect_by_path(seqno, '/') as path,
       seqno,
       cs_prev_seqno,
       descr,
       level
  from data2
 where id = 1
connect by prior id_seqno = cs_id_prev_seqno
 start with cs_prev_seqno = 0;
```

-->

```
id path   seq seq_prev descr       level
1 /1      1   0        Id 1 Step1  1
1 /1/2    2   1        Id 1 Step2  2
1 /1/2/3  3   2        Id 1 Step3  3
1 /1/4    4   1        Id 1 Step4  2
```

But I guess there should be an easier way to achieve this?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CONNECT BY` to restrict connections to the same `ID`:

```
CONNECT BY PRIOR id = id
       AND PRIOR seqno = cs_id_prev_seqno
```

Which would make your query:

```
SELECT     id,
           SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(seqno, '/') AS path,
           seqno,
           cs_prev_seqno,
           descr,
           level
FROM       data d
WHERE      id = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR id = id
       AND PRIOR seqno = cs_id_prev_seqno
START WITH cs_prev_seqno = 0;
```

> I expected that the `connect by` is only done for rows with id=1

As you found out, this is not true. The query will find all the rows where:

- The root row has `cs_prev_seqno = 0` (as per the `START WITH` clause);
- The current row has `id = 1` (the `WHERE` clause); and
- That, **at each step**, from the root to the current row the `CONNECT BY` clause is satisfied.

If the `CONNECT BY` clause does not specify that the `ID` should be constant then it will not be checked on those intervening steps.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, you can try limiting dataset before applying the `CONNECT BY`, for example:

```
with data(id, seqno, cs_prev_seqno, descr) as
 (select 1, 1, 0, 'Id 1 Step1' from dual union all
  select 1, 2, 1, 'Id 1 Step2' from dual union all
  select 1, 3, 2, 'Id 1 Step3' from dual  union all
  select 1, 4, 1, 'Id 1 Step4' from dual union all
  select 2, 1, 0, 'Id 2 Step1' from dual  union all
  select 2, 2, 1, 'Id 2 Step2' from dual)
select id,
       sys_connect_by_path(seqno, '/') as path,
       seqno,
       cs_prev_seqno,
       descr,
       level
  from ( select * from data where id = 1)
connect by prior seqno = cs_prev_seqno
 start with cs_prev_seqno = 0;
```

You could even use your condition in the `CONNECT BY` clause:

```
with data(id, seqno, cs_prev_seqno, descr) as
 (select 1, 1, 0, 'Id 1 Step1' from dual union all
  select 1, 2, 1, 'Id 1 Step2' from dual union all
  select 1, 3, 2, 'Id 1 Step3' from dual  union all
  select 1, 4, 1, 'Id 1 Step4' from dual union all
  select 2, 1, 0, 'Id 2 Step1' from dual  union all
  select 2, 2, 1, 'Id 2 Step2' from dual)
select id,
       sys_connect_by_path(seqno, '/') as path,
       seqno,
       cs_prev_seqno,
       descr,
       level
from data where id = 1
connect by prior seqno = cs_prev_seqno
         and prior id = 1
 start with cs_prev_seqno = 0;
```